# SQL*Loader installation

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to install SQL*Loader without installing the whole Oracle package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In the client install package, custom installation, you can select database utilities as part of the install, which should get you SQL*Loader, among other things.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html

I can't find SQL*Loader there.

Comment: No, not the instant client, you'll need to install from the full Oracle Client package. I don't think SQL*Loader will work with the instant client, so you'll need a minimal runtime oracle client install.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/oracle10g/htdocs/10201winsoft.html is the 10gR2 client for MS Windows.

Answer (score 2):

the comments above were what i was looking for.

the "instant client" has sqlplus, but does not have sqlldr.

sqlldr requres the (full) "client" which is hidden off of a tiny fine print link on the craptacular oracle site.

"Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)"
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html

Comment: Gosh, thank you. Took me all morning just to install that one program... at least I'm motivated because we use it to finally get away from oracle.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, there is also a way to install SQL*Loader with instant clients: http://kimplove.blogspot.de/2010/08/installation-of-oracle-instant-client.html

I'm quite sure it is not supported by Oracle and you need a client installation like DCookie explained. But it could be a solution when you need to install it on multiple servers.

The alternative solution would be to make a installation like DCookie explained and create a rpm/deb from it and push it to multiple servers.